# SQL - Join two tables without unique fields

Tags: sql

This is my first post in this forum so please be understanding.

I have following issue.

I want to two join two tables:

Table1:

```
Product  | Start Date  | End Date
-------------------------------------
Product1 | 01/01/2014  | 01/05/2015
Product2 | 01/03/2014  | 01/01/2015
```

Table2:

```
Product   | Start Date | End Date   | Value
--------------------------------------------
Product1  | 01/01/2014 | 01/02/2015 |  10
Product1  | 02/02/2014 | 01/04/2015 |  15
Product1  | 02/04/2014 | 01/05/2015 |  15
Product2  | 01/03/2014 | 04/05/2014 |   5
Product2  | 05/05/2014 | 01/01/2015 |   5
```

To have a table with latest value like:

```
Product   | Start Date   | End Date   | Value
------------------------------------------------
Product1  | 02/04/2014   | 01/05/2015 |   15
Product2  | 05/05/2014   | 01/01/2015 |    5
```

I need to join them and not use just the second table because both of them have more unique columns that I need to use.

I was thinking about firstly using some kind of IF function on second table to make one row per product (the one with latest start date) and than join it simply then with first table. But I have no idea how to do the first part.

I am really looking forward for your help.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: So, it sound like Product+Start+End are unique in the Table1, but repeated in Table2. Is that right? Do you want to sum the value from Table2?

Comment: How do you decide which row to use from `Table2`?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GuranjanSingh   OP wants "the one with latest start date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use WHERE NOT EXISTS to filter out everything but the latest date from TABLE2 (I am assuming that you are asking for the latest STARTDATE from TABLE2; also I add 'SomeOtherField' to Table1, because otherwise you could just query Table2):

SELECT t1.Product, t1.SomeOtherField, t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate, t2.Value

FROM Table1 t1

JOIN (SELECT a.Product, a.StartDate, a.EndDate, a.Value FROM Table2 a

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 b

WHERE b.Product = a.Product AND b.StartDate > a.StartDate)) t2

ON (t2.Product = t1.Product)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, the query will involve three steps:

1. Find all the max `start date` for each `product` in table 2. Hint: use group by.
2. Join table 2 with the result from #1 to get the `Value`.
3. Join table 1 with the result from #2 to filter out products that are not in table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need `Table1` at all in your example, you just need to aggregate `Table2` to find the `MAX([Start Date]` for each `Product`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table2 a
JOIN (SELECT Product,MAX([Start Date]) AS Mx_Start_Dt   
      FROM Table2
      GROUP BY Product   
      ) b
   ON   a.Product = b.Product
    AND a.[Start Date] = b.Mx_Start_Dt
```

If you do need to bring in fields from `Table` you can just add another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM Table1 a
JOIN (SELECT a.*
      FROM Table2 a
      JOIN (SELECT Product,MAX([Start Date]) AS Mx_Start_Dt   
            FROM Table2
            GROUP BY Product   
           ) b
        ON a.Product = b.Product
           AND a.[Start Date] = b.Mx_Start_Dt
      ) c
  ON a.Product = b.Product
```

If using a database that supports analytic functions, you can make it cleaner via the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY [Start Date] DESC) AS RN
              FROM Table2
              )
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
JOIN cte b
  ON a.Product = b.Product
   AND b.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `ROW_NUMBER` in SQLServer:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY StartDate DESC) RN
    FROM @T
 ) Results
WHERE RN = 1
```